Lightgallery fails to render image
I am looking for a gallery that has thumbnails, is opened upon click on image and has captions. lightgalleryjs does meet my requirements, but it does not render the image. it shows black screen overlay instead, without the image above the overlay.
code:
inside head tag:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lightgallery.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lg-thumbnail.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lg-autoplay.min.css">

inside body:
       <div class="gallery1" id="gallery1">
    <a href="assets/images/events/IMG_2464.JPG" 
      >
      <img src="assets/images/events/IMG_2475.JPG" alt="">
    </a>

    <a href="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG">
      <img src="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG">
      <img src="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG">
      <img src="assets/images/events/IMG_4713.JPG" alt="">
    </a>

   </div>

at the bottom above body closing tag:
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/share/lg-share.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/thumbnail/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/autoplay/lg-autoplay.min.js"></script>
<script>
  let gallery = document.getElementById("gallery1");
  lightGallery(gallery, {        
    controls: false,
    speed: 200,
    download: false,
    counter: false,
    plugins: [ lgThumbnail, lgAutoplay],
  })
</script>


Your code works fine for me.
Are you sure that your image paths are correct?
The only change I made in this working code snippet, is changing the image paths.


let gallery = document.getElementById("gallery1");

lightGallery(gallery, {
  controls: false,
  speed: 200,
  download: false,
  counter: false,
  plugins: [ lgThumbnail, lgAutoplay],
})
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lightgallery.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lg-thumbnail.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/css/lg-autoplay.min.css">


        <div class="gallery1" id="gallery1">
          <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
          </a>

          <a href="https://picsum.photos/201/300">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/201/300" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="https://picsum.photos/202/300">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/202/300" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="https://picsum.photos/203/300">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/203/300" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>



    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/share/lg-share.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/thumbnail/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/2.7.2/plugins/autoplay/lg-autoplay.min.js"></script>




Just checked it, your code snippet doesn't work on my current index.html but when tried different html file, it works. even my images work. what could be the issue?
